# Is it OK to name stories after songs?

Tags: creative-writing, titles

I've been writing a story for a while, initially and continuing to be inspired by the song "People Are Strange" by The Doors. For a majority of that time, I've called the story *People Are Strange* because it fit with the themes of suspicion, and alienation (when you're a stranger.)

Is this considered to be "in bad taste", or is it OK? The book is a fantasy, if that changes much.

Answer (score 2):

TVtropes has a [list](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TitledAfterTheSong) of works named after song titles or allusions to lyrics from songs.  It also sorts them into works that reference the song or works that just make use of lyrics or titles of songs.  They also have a separate list for works that were wholly inspired by the story of a song or a group of songs related by the album or artist.

One notable find is that there are two separate films titled "Rocketman" after the Elton John song.  One is a 2019 biopic about the singer, while the other is a 90s family comedy about a group of astronauts on a mission to Mars.